# Database schema for values that are dependent on another value

Tags: sql, database-design, dependencies, database-schema

What I'm trying to do is enter this data into a database for use on a userform.

For example, if a user selects Product A in the Product dropdown list then the Style dropdown list will populate only with the Styles available for Product A and will have the default Style selected. And the Color droplist will only show the Colors that correspond to that Style. So essentially what I have here are values that are dependent on another value. The list of colors depends on the Style which depends on the Product Type.

What is the sane database schema for this scenario? I have been racking my brain for several days now and would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Product Types (A, B, C, D, E)

### Product A & B

Comes in the following Styles:

Style 1

Style 2 (Default)

Style 3

### Product C & D

Comes in the following Styles:

Style 4 (Default)

Style 5

### Product E

Comes in only one Style:

Style 6

Style 7 (Default)

NOTE: Each Style has it's own unique set of colors

NOTE: Each Product has a default Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logical design, you should be able to translate this directly to a SQL dialect.

Note that everything here is NOT NULL.

---

*Product (PROD_NAME) exists.*

```
Product {PROD_NAME}
    KEY {PROD_NAME}
```

*Style (STYLE_NO) exists.*

```
Style {STYLE_NO}
  KEY {STYLE_NO}
```

*Colour (CLR_NAME) exists.*

```
Colour {CLR_NAME}
  KEY  {CLR_NAME}
```

*Style (STYLE_NO) is available in colour (CLR_NAME).*

*For each style, it is possible for that style to be available in more than one colour.
For each colour it is possible that more than one style is available in that colour.*

If a style is available in a colour, then that style must exist and that colour must exist.

```
StyleColour {STYLE_NO, CLR_NAME}
        KEY {STYLE_NO, CLR_NAME}

FOREIGN KEY {STYLE_NO} REFERENCES Style  {STYLE_NO}
FOREIGN KEY {CLR_NAME} REFERENCES Colour {CLR_NAME}
```

*Product (PROD_NAME) is available in style (STYLE_NO).*

*For each product, it is possible for that product to be available in more than one style. For each style, it is possible than more than one product is available in that style.*

*If a product is available in a style then that product must exist and that style must exist.*

```
ProductStyle {PROD_NAME, STYLE_NO}
         KEY {PROD_NAME, STYLE_NO}

FOREIGN KEY {PROD_NAME} REFERENCES Product {PROD_NAME}
FOREIGN KEY {STYLE_NO}  REFERENCES Style   {STYLE_NO}
```

*Style (STYLE_NO) is default for product (PROD_NAME)*

*Each product has at most one default style; for each style, it is possible that more than one product has that style as default.*

*If a style is default for a product then that product must be available in that style.*

```
DefaultProductStyle {PROD_NAME, STYLE_NO}
                KEY {PROD_NAME} 

FOREIGN KEY {PROD_NAME, STYLE_NO}  REFERENCES ProductStyle {PROD_NAME, STYLE_NO}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Are there a total of 6 tables in this solution? Product, Style, Color, StyleColor, ProductStyle, and DefaultProductStyle.

Comment: @SalvatoreLibrizzi, yes six -- the first three are mostly "static data" used to define Product, Style, and Colour domains.

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages about this solution vs the one that Boris gave?

Comment: @SalvatoreLibrizzi take a look at constraints. I think me and Boris are reading business rules differently. I do not see in that model how to have `style = 2` associated with `product = A` and `product = B`. (same for styles 1,3); also for  association of styles 4,5 with products C,D ? In that model each style can be associated with exactly one product. Same for colours. I guess it depends how you use logic, is colour red different for `tie-narrow-red` and `tie-wide-red` ?

Comment: @SalvatoreLibrizzi; added the model image, maybe it is easier to understand it this way.

Comment: Thanks Damir! That diagram cleared things up and we're in agreement with the business rules. I will mark this as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things simple:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_products
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE styles (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_styles
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_styles_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES products (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE colors (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    style_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_colors
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_colors_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (style_id)
        REFERENCES styles (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If you want to have it more complicated you could try to avoid duplicities (i.e. reuse the colors, etc), but this is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Boris! A couple of questions... So in this schema there would be multiple entries in the Styles table for the same style because a style could belong to several Products. Correct? Where I'm confused then is you could have a particular color referencing a style, but it could be several entries for that one particular style.

Comment: Let's have an example: I am your customer and I purchased a tie. In the order you save `color_id=3965`. In colors you can find that ID - it's `pink checked` referencing `style_id=2038`. In styles you can find this ID - it's `narrow` referencing `product_id=706`. This ID in products says it is a `tie`. But if we go back: the `tie` may be in 2 styles (`usual`, `narrow`) and each style can have colors (`usual`: `red`, `yellow with stripes`, `purple dotted` and `narrow`: `red`, `pink checked`). Both styles have `red`, but it's a different red, defined specifically for each style.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following database schema:

1) Table_Product: Product_ID, Product_Name (List of all Products).

2) Table_Style: Style_ID, Style_Name (List of all Style)

3) Table_Color: Color_ID, Color_Name (List of all Colors)

4) Table_Product_Style: Product_ID, Style_ID, IsDefault (Mapping of Product & Style with Default style for each product)

5) Table_Style_Color: Style_ID, Color_ID (Mapping of Style & Color)

6) Table_User_Preference: User_ID, Product_ID, Style_ID, Color_ID.